# ActionScript Implicit Coercion Error

Tags: php, ajax, actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to ActionScript and Flash environments (just started) and I'm trying to get data from a .php file.
So I found [this AjaxRequest class](http://positionabsolute.net/blog/2008/12/actionscript-ajax-request.php) on the internet.

And I'm testing it with my Main actionscript class, which is in the same package with *AjaxRequest.as*

My function (constructor of *HelloWorld.as*) is:

```
// Create a TextField object and set its content to my php (AJAX) output
var t:TextField = new TextField( );
//Line 38 is this :
t.htmlText=new AjaxRequest("http://localhost/my_ajax_agent.php?action=flash");
addChild(t);
```

When I run the flash file that has main class as *HelloWorld.as*, I get the following error:

```
C:\path\to\HelloWorld.as, Line 38 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type pakaj:AjaxRequest to an unrelated type String.
```

**Edit**:
My question is this :

What should I do in order to get an AJAX call's result as a String?

**Thanks for any help !**

**Note:** My *ajax_agent.php* file only does this.

```
if(@$_GET['action']=="flash"){echo "Hello World";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong because you're trying to assign AjaxRequest to String (TextField's htmlText property is String-typed).

You have to write a link into your htmlText, using HTML "a href" tag.

If you want a request result, then you have to add event listener to request and execute it. When your request is comleted, the event will trigger, and you can retrieve String result data from it. So, put this data into your TextField's htmlText.

Comment: He wants a request result in that TextField.

Comment: @Vesper yes I want that. So my real question is what should I write to get the result as string ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive anything from that request you have to call `AjaxRequest.send()` first, and then you have to wait until that request will return data (query `URLLoader.data` AFTER it will receive its own `Event.COMPLETE` event). Anything that's involving external data sources is asynchronous, meaning the result isn't available immediately. Of course you cannot directly receive that request's result, so assigning `new AjaxRequest()` to a TextField is rightfully erroneous. The error says just that. Use [this manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and [this set of instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html) to learn how to employ loaders and receive what did they load.